# Listing records by 'sortorder' in Bolt CMS template not following numerical value

Tags: sorting, twig, bolt-cms

I have a contenttype called "courses" which I would like to list in a specific order. I'm able to do so in the backend *(by setting `has_sortorder: true` for the corresponding taxonomy)*, but I am not able to get the records to list in the same order in my "courses.twig" listing template. Here's a snippet from "courses.twig" where I'm outputting the list of records:

```
<ul>
  {% for record in records|order('sortorder') %}
  <li>Name: {{ record.title }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The output is not following the numerical 'sortorder' value as defined in the backend. Seems like a trivial thing, but I'm completely stumped.

Could anyone offer clues or tell me if I missed anything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(1) Use `{{ dump(record) }}` to check if your record has a `sortorder` field.

(2) A contenttype definition can have a `listing_sort` field. Have you tried that?